# C# MVC4 Save HTML in Textarea - Validation failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page creation form, using a Page class

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using SpringHealthOne.SpringWS;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SpringHealthOne.Models
{
    public class Page 
    {
        public int PageID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public MvcHtmlString PageBody { get; set; }

        public string Body
        {
            get { return PageBody.ToHtmlString(); }
            set { PageBody = new MvcHtmlString(value); }
        }

        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The form itself is simple enough, it includes a textarea with Ckeditor added to it. When trying to save the field initially i was getting unsafe input errors (the HTML), so i added `[ValidateInput(false)]` to the method:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Page page)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(page);
    }
```

I no longer get an exception, but the ModelState.IsValid is always set to false, and i get the error of:

```
The value '<HTML STRING>' is invalid.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Im very new to C# and more so MVC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`AllowHtmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is what you're looking for. You can use it like this:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

This allows you to use HTML markup in the string since it skips model validation for this property. You should not need the `ValidateInput` attribute. I don't think it's good to use it anyway, since it skips validation for the whole model, this might also cause the `ModelState.IsValid` property to be `false` since you skipped the validation. Also see [this article](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.nl/2012/12/allowhtml-attribute-to-allow-html-for.html).

Comment: I've changed my Model to add the `[AllowHTML]`, and i have removed the `[ValidateInput(false)]` from the Controller.

Im back to getting an exception again:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (PageBody="<h2 style="font-styl...").`

Comment: @N1ghteyes have you added it to the right property on the model? The exception complains about the `PageBody` property.

Comment: PageBody is of type `MvcHtmlString` but i have also added [AllowHtml] to that, the result is no more exception, but im back to the validation error again

Comment: @N1ghteyes then perhaps there is something more wrong, can you examine the `ModelState` property and see what's wrong?

Comment: It seems to be to do with how i was origonally handling Html input.

I've changed the model to only use pagebody and not try to encoide the html. all is working now :)